# how to ask for input again c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, input, cin

My question is how I ask the user if he/she wants to input again.
ex.
do you want to calculate again? yes or no.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and fix the error.

```
int main() {
}
int a;
cout << endl << "Write 1 for addition and 0 for substraction:" << endl;
cin >> a;

// addition
if (a == 1) {
    cout << "You are now about to add two number together, ";
    cout << "enter a number: " << endl;
    int b;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "one more: " << endl;
    int c;
    cin >> c;
    cout << b + c;
}
//Substraction
else if (a == 0) {
    cout << "enter a number: " << endl;
    int b;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "one more: " << endl;
    int c;
    cin >> c;
    cout << b - c;
}
//If not 1 or 0 was called
else {
    cout << "Text" << endl;

}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One question more, could i ahve done this in a much easier way?

Comment: Are you familiar with loops?

Comment: @DavidAndersson Yes. Once the code works as intended you may create a quesion on [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), there you'll get detailed answers on how you can improve your code.

Comment: concerning your question in the comment: most of the code in the `if` and in the `else` block is identical. You can make it shorter by putting only that part that is different in the `if`/`else`

Comment: Who put this? `else {cout << "A bad word" << endl}`

Comment: The author of the code, who else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    string calculateagain = "yes";
    do
    { 
        //... Your Code
        cout << "Do you want to calculate again? (yes/no) "
        cin >> calculateagain;
    } while(calculateagain != "no");
    return 0;
}
```

Important things to note:

1. This is not checked, so user input may be invalid, but the loop will run again.
2. You need to include `<string>` to use strings.

**Simplified Calculation Code**

```
int a;
cout << endl << "Write 1 for addition and 0 for substraction:" << endl;
cin >> a;
cout << "enter a number: " << endl;
int b;
cin >> b;
cout << "one more: " << endl;
int c;
cin >> c;
// addition
if (a == 1) {
    cout << b + c;
}
//Substraction
else if (a == 0) {
    cout << b - c;
}
//If not 1 or 0 was called
else {
    cout << "Invalid number!\n";
    continue; //restart the loop

}
```

This code should be inside the `do ... while` loop.

Comment: Thanks, but i dont understand how if we take cin << calculateagain; and then say while(calculateagain != "no"); works because calculateagain value is yes already, so what my question really is why it dont stop at cout <<  "Do you want to calculate again? (yes/no) ";
   cin >> calculateagain; since it already valued yes from the the string calculateagain = "yes";

Comment: that was really unclear question i hope you understand, excuse my bad english.

Comment: Because, that is just a default value. The user will no matter what change it with `cin`

Comment: Also remember there is no checking `Yes` is just a default value. It could be anything else.