# about asking the user to input again when invalid input occurs [c++]

Tags: c++, if-statement, visual-c++, while-loop, cin

```
//User input
cout << "Please enter the property value: ";
while (true)
{
    cin >> property_value;
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Please enter the valid data." << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the property value again:" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

I want to ask the user to reinput again when the user input the invalid data, e.g. some letters.  However when I try to run it, it keeps showing "Please enter the valid data." and "Please enter the property value again:", it enters an infinite loop.  I already check some post also about this problem, but my code is similar to them. Please help.
P.S. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What post did you check?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193327/how-to-ask-for-input-again-c and etc.

Comment: Insert `cin.clear()` at the end of the first `if`.

Comment: it still keeps showing those two cout. =[

Comment: //User input
 cout << "Please enter the property value: ";
 while (true)
 {
  cin >> property_value;
  if (cin.fail())
  {
   cin.clear();
   cout << "Please enter the valid data." << endl;
   cout << "Please enter the property value again:" << endl;
  }
  else
  {
   break;
  }
 }

Comment: How about cin.ignore() ? I saw some post talking about this. sorry that i am new to c++, what mean by cin.ignore() ? isnt cin.clear already clear the data that inputed?